# JavaScript pixel by pixel canvas manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm working on a simple web app which simplifies the colours of an uploaded image to a colour palette selected by the user. The script works, but it takes a really long time to loop through the whole image (for large images it's over a few minutes), changing the pixels.

Initially, I was writing to the canvas itself, but I changed the code so that changes are made to an `ImageData` object and the canvas is only updated at the end of the script. However, this didn't really make much difference.

```
// User selects colours:
colours = [[255,45,0], [37,36,32], [110,110,105], [18,96,4]];

function colourDiff(colour1, colour2) {
    difference = 0
    difference += Math.abs(colour1[0] - colour2[0]);
    difference += Math.abs(colour1[1] - colour2[1]);
    difference += Math.abs(colour1[2] - colour2[2]);
    return(difference);
}

function getPixel(imgData, index) {
    return(imgData.data.slice(index*4, index*4+4));
}

function setPixel(imgData, index, pixelData) {
    imgData.data.set(pixelData, index*4);
}

data = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
for(i=0; i<(canvas.width*canvas.height); i++) {
    pixel = getPixel(data, i);
    lowestDiff = 1024;
    lowestColour = [0,0,0];
    for(colour in colours) {
        colour = colours[colour];
        difference = colourDiff(colour, pixel);
        if(lowestDiff < difference) {
            continue;
        }
        lowestDiff = difference;
        lowestColour = colour;
    }
    console.log(i);
    setPixel(data, i, lowestColour);
}
ctx.putImageData(data, 0, 0);
```

During the entire process, the website is completely frozen, so I can't even display a progress bar. Is there any way to optimise this so that it takes less time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to slice the array each iteration. (As niklas has already stated).

I would loop over the data array instead of looping over the canvas dimensions and directly edit the array.

```
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i+=4) { // i+=4 to step over each r,g,b,a pixel
  let pixel = getPixel(data, i);
  ...
  setPixel(data, i, lowestColour);
}

function setPixel(data, i, colour) {
    data[i] = colour[0];
    data[i+1] = colour[1];
    data[i+2] = colour[2];
}

function getPixel(data, i) {
    return [data[i], data[i+1], data[i+2]];
}
```

Also, console.log can bring a browser to it's knees if you've got the console open. If your image is 1920 x 1080 then you will be logging to the console 2,073,600 times.

You can also pass all of the processing off to a Web Worker for ultimate threaded performance. Eg. https://jsfiddle.net/pnmz75xa/

Answer (score 0):

One problem or option for improvement is clearly your `slice` function, which will create a new array every time it is called, you do not need this. I would change the for loop like so:

```
for y in canvas.height {
  for x in canvas.width {
    //directly alter the canvas' pixels
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Finding difference in color

I am adding an answer because you have use a very poor color match algorithm.

Finding how closely a color matches another is best done if you imagine each unique possible colour as a point in 3D space. The red, green, and blue values represent the x,y,z coordinate.

You can then use some basic geometry to locate the distance from one colour to the another.

```
// the two colours as bytes 0-255
const colorDist = (r1, g1, b1, r2, g2, b2) => Math.hypot(r1 - r2, g1 - g2, b1 - b2);
```

It is also important to note that the channel value 0-255 is a compressed value, the actual intensity is close to that value squared (`channelValue ** 2.2`). That means that red = 255 is 65025 times more intense than red = 1

The following function is a close approximation of the colour difference between two colors. Avoiding the `Math.hypot` function as it is very slow.

```
 const pallet = [[1,2,3],[2,10,30]]; // Array of arrays representing rgb byte 
                                     // of the colors you are matching
 function findClosest(r,g,b) {  
     var closest;
     var dist = Infinity;
     r *= r;
     g *= g;
     b *= b;
     for (const col of pallet) {
        const d = ((r - col[0] * col[0]) + (g - col[1] * col[1]) + (b - col[2] * col[2])) ** 0.5;
        if (d < dist) {
            if (d === 0) { // if same then return result
                return col;
            }
            closest = col;
            dist = d;
        }
    }
    return closest;
  }
```

As for performance, your best bet is either via a web worker, or use webGL to do the conversion in realtime.

If you want to keep it simple to prevent the code from blocking the page cut the job into smaller slices using a timer to allow the page breathing room.

The example uses `setTimeout` and `performance.now()` to do 10ms slices letting other page events and rendering to do there thing. It returns a promise that resolves when all pixels are processed

```
  function convertBitmap(canvas, maxTime) { // maxTime in ms (1/1000 second)
     return new Promise(allDone => {
         const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
         const pixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
         const data = pixels.data;
         var idx = data.length / 4;
         processPixels(); // start processing
         function processPixels() {
             const time = performance.now();
             while (idx-- > 0) {
                 if (idx % 1024) { // check time every 1024 pixels
                      if (performance.now() - time > maxTime) {
                          setTimeout(processPixels, 0);
                          idx++;
                          return;
                      }
                 }
                 let i = idx * 4;
                 const col = findClosest(data[i], data[i + 1], data[i + 2]);
                 data[i++] = col[0];
                 data[i++] = col[1];
                 data[i] = col[2];
             }
             ctx.putImageData(pixels, 0, 0);
             allDone("Pixels processed");
         }
      });
  }

  // process pixels in 10ms slices. 
  convertBitmap(myCanvas, 10).then(mess => console.log(mess));
```